# Can't understand the output

Tags: c, pointers

Code looks like this.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int vals[2];
    char *x;
    int *v, *v2, *v3;
    vals[0] = 0x00ABCDEF;
    vals[1] = 0x12345678;

    x = (char *) &vals[0];
    v = (int *) (x + 1);
    v2 = (int *) (x+2);
    v3 = (int *) (x+3);

    printf ("%x \n", *x); /*0x EF */
    printf ("%x \n", *v); /*0x 7800ABCD */
    printf ("%x \n", *v2); /*0x 567800AB */
    printf ("%x \n", *v3); /*0x 34567800 */
}
```

The values in the comment is the output.
could you explain how x points to EF and also v , v2, v3.
what is the explanation to that. i know that one hex digit is four bits and one int can store 8 hex digits but can't understand how the x points to EF and not 00 which are the first two letters and why the last two letters and not the first two.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: BTW Alignment restriction violation.

Comment: [What is the strict aliasing rule?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Answer (score 2):

If your system has alignment requirements, then `v = (int *) (x + 1);` (and the next two lines) cause undefined behaviour due to an alignment violation.

But even if they don't, `*v` later on causes undefined behaviour by violating the strict aliasing rule. The expression `*v` has type `int` , and it is not allowed to use this type of expression to access `char` objects (or in fact any objects other than `int`, `unsigned int` or const-qualified versions of those).

[Undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) means that anything may happen, including nonsense output or otherwise.